# Postgres update with ST_Union error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, error

first of all im not a pro in pg requests, and sorry for my English level,
so all i want is to update a geom column in a table t1 (with a gid pk) with union of this column and another one from another table, to make it easy here is my code:

```
UPDATE t1 SET geom = (select ST_Union(geom,other_geom) from t1, t2 where t1.gid = t2.gid)
```

and it gaves me an error :

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
État SQL :21000
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the subquery:

```
(SELECT ST_Union(geom, other_geom) from t1, t2 WHERE t1.gid = t2.gid)
```

returns multiple rows, while your update says to update table t1, but without any reference to gid, so the query analyzer doesn't know which row to update. You need to use gid in the subquery and then use this in the where clause of the update, to relate each row of t1 with each row of the union of t1 and t2.

```
UPDATE t1 SET geom = foo.geom 
FROM
  (SELECT 
       t1.gid, ST_Union(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS geom 
     FROM t1, t2 
    WHERE t1.gid = t2.gid
  ) foo
WHERE t1.gid = foo.gid;
```

and now foo.id refers to the row in the subquery equivalent to t1.id, which allows the update to update each row of t1 correctly. Note, you also have to alias ST_Union(t1.geom, t2.geom) with AS geom, otherwise the update query will complain about foo.geom not existing.

Comment: i will try whit this request

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted the WHERE t1.gid = t2.gid in the subquery. If you drop that, you will get the union of all the geoms in t1 against all the geoms in t2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have more than one record in t2 where id = t1.id. You can check it by:

```
select t1.id, count(*)
from t1
join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
having count(*)>1
```

If this is wrong you have to repair your data, if it's right you have to join all objects from t2 before joining them to t1, so:

```
UPDATE t1 SET geom = (ST_Union(geom,
                  (select ST_Union(other_geom) from t2 where t2.id=id)))
```